How to E2E test bull.js?
TLDR:
I need a way to pass time in @nestjs/bulljs and do "the task scheduled for future" now.
More Details:
I'm trying to write a mini game with nestjs that uses stock markets data for prediction.
As a part of this game, I have set up @nestjs/bulljs to do this: Whenever user predicts any stock, it will be added to somePredictionQueue with a delay of 1 hour. After that time, the consumer will be fired and will check correctness of users prediction.
const predictionJob = await this.somePredictionQueue.add(
  predictionData,
  {
    jobId: uuidv4(),
    delay: 60 * 60 * 1000, //one hour delay
  },
);

This way, user's predicted price will be locked in now and in an hour, another function is called to check if the predicted price has been hit, and if so, gives the user a trophy.
Here is the problem:
How can I write E2E tests to simulate this condition? It's not logical to wait 1 hour for 1 test to complete. Is there a way to pass time in jest?
Here are some things i have already tried:

Advancing Jest timers manually.

jest.advanceTimersByTime(....); //simulating passage of time and checking if the user has the trophy.

This just does nothing, no matter how much i advance the timers by (even up to a month). I don't know why.

Manually triggering the Bulljs consumer.

const queue = await moduleRef.get(PredictionService).somePredictionQueue;
const job = queue.getDelayed(); //getting the job that is scheduled to be fired in the future.

await moduleRef.get(WaitingPredictionsConsumer).check(job[0]);

This works! But only sometimes. If I run the test that is doing this by itself, using it.only() it will work 90% of the times, but when i run the full test suit, this will work 10% of the times!
Answer to some possible questions:

I am using a brand new database per test. I'm starting a postgres transaction in beforeEach and will roll it back in the afterEach. This has not caused any problem so far.

Users prediction is always spot on! I am manually giving it the prices for the next hour, so it is not that some times price will go up and sometimes down.


